# Child class not able to access the contents present in the ArrayList of parent class

Tags: java, arraylist

```
abstract class PayRoll
{
    List<String> nm=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> dob=new ArrayList<String>();
}


class Employee extends PayRoll implements PayEmpInt
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n;
    String ename,eid,birth,pr_id;
    public void addEmployee()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter the number\t :");
            n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            System.out.print("\nEnter Employee name\t :");
            ename=br.readLine();
            System.out.print("\nEnter the Employee ID\t :");
            eid=br.readLine();
            System.out.print("\nEnter the D.O.B(mm-dd-yyy)\t :");
            birth=br.readLine();
            nm.add(ename);
            id.add(eid);
            dob.add(birth);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print("\nError while handling the Input. "+e);
    }
}


class Project extends Employee
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print("\nName\t\tID\t\tDOB");
        for(int i=0;i<id.size();i++)
        System.out.println(nm.get(i)+"\t"+id.get(i)+"\n"+dob.get(i));
    }
}

import java.io.*;

class PayMain
{
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
  {
   int ch;
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   while(true)
   {
    System.out.println("\nOptions:\n\t1. Employee DB\n\t2. Projects\n\t3. Exit");
    ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
    Employee e=new Employee();
    e.addEmployee();
    System.out.print("\nEMPLOYEE LIST");
    e.employeeDetails();
    break;
    case 2:
    Project p=new Project();
    p.display();
    break;
    case 3:
    System.exit(0);
    }
   }
 }
```

}

I'm able to call the method addEmployee from the main class. After adding employees, when I try to call the method display(present in Project), it doesn't print the contents of the List.

I don't know why Project is not able to access the values of the List that are present in its parent class, Employee.

**Edit :**
Added the main class. The thing is that I use addEmployee method to add new employees and employeeDetails display everything perfectly. But when I call p.search(), it doesn't display anything other than NAME    ID    DOB.

**Note :**
And pardon me for the weird design. I'm new to Java. I'm doing a mini-project on employee management system(without using any DB software). So suggest me how to design it. Thanks!

Comment: Please show me the main class. I suspect you may have multiple instantiations.

Comment: Weird design. Why is a ``Project`` an ``Employee``? Strongly suggest to consider re-thinking your structure.

Comment: I agree with @qqilihq, this is a weird architecture. I think project shouldn't extend anything. Also an employee isn't really a payroll.

Answer (score 1):

I need to see your main method. When I ran my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Project aProject = new Project();

    aProject.addEmployee();
    aProject.display();
}
```

I get the following output (with my sample inputs):

Enter the number     :2

Enter Employee name  :bob

Enter the Employee ID    :123

Enter the D.O.B(mm-dd-yyy)   :01-01-2222

Enter Employee name  :alice

Enter the Employee ID    :234

Enter the D.O.B(mm-dd-yyy)   :04-44-4444

Name        ID      DOBbob  123
01-01-2222
alice   234
04-44-4444

You need to make sure you're calling the methods on the same object.

Also, you may want to update the addEmployee method to addEmployees, since it prompts you for the number to add.

Answer (score 0):

The fields of the abstract class Payroll have no modifier, which means they can only be accessed by classes in the same package.  They should be `protected`.  Or else provide a `public` getter if appropriate.  (Here I'd say no)

I agree with the others that the architecture feels weird.